# Get average run-time of a C program

Tags: c, runtime

I'm trying to measure differences in speed of reading and writing misaligned vs aligned bits into binary files. I would like to know is there an utility I can use (Except for running `time` over & over again and writing my own) to sample an average run-time of a program (I'm running Linux based OS)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> running `time` over & over again and writing my own

That's fine. You can perform the read/write ten thousand times both ways and compute the average time.

If you really want to use a library you can try [Google Perftools](http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/).

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a header file:

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

#include <stdlib>
#include <sys/time.h>

typedef unsigned long long timestamp_t;

static timestamp_t

get_timestamp ()
{
  struct timeval now;
  gettimeofday (&now, NULL);
  return  now.tv_usec + (timestamp_t)now.tv_sec * 1000000;
}
#endif
```

Include the header file into whichever .c file you'll be using, and do something like this:

```
#define N 10000
int main()
{
    int i;
    double avg;
    timestamp_t start, end;

    start = get_timestamp();
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        foo();
    end = get_timestamp();
    avg = (end - start) / (double)N;

    printf("%f", avg);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically this calls whichever function you're trying to measure performance of N times, where N is a defined constant (doesn't have to be) in this case. It takes a timestamp before the for loop and after the for loop and then calculates the average time it's taken for the function to execute. The get_timestamp() function returns the number of microseconds, so if you need milliseconds, divide by 1000, seconds - divide by 1000000 etc.